# How to get a PowerShell available list of events, methods, and properties For GUI using Xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, powershell, forms, xaml

I want to know   available list of events, methods, and properties For GUI using Xaml in Powershell

Get-Member -MemberType "Event"

Get-Member -MemberType "Method"

Get-Member -MemberType "Property"

This script code is not enough.

I was trying to this Sample Code:

[Powershell_Xaml_Form_AllEvent_Method_Property_Sample](https://gist.github.com/papanda925/b8a7843ca6c75b9e53d084d9404021ab)

In this code, I got a list in this Script

```
Write-Host "# ------------------------- Event ------------------------- "
$ret  = ($window | Get-Member -MemberType "Event") 
$ret |  Where-Object{ 
    Write-Host ("#TypeName:   " + $_.TypeName) 
    Write-Host ("#Definition: " + $_.Definition ) 
    Write-Host ("#Name:       " + $_.Name) 
    Write-Host ("#MemberType: " + $_.MemberType) 
    Write-Host (" $" + "window.ADD_" + $_.name + "{   write-host """ + $_.name + """ }")
}

Write-Host "# ------------------------- Method ------------------------- "
$ret  = ($window | Get-Member -MemberType "Method") 
$ret |  Where-Object{ 
    Write-Host ("#TypeName:   " + $_.TypeName) 
    Write-Host ("#Definition: " + $_.Definition ) 
    Write-Host ("#Name:       " + $_.Name) 
    Write-Host ("#MemberType: " + $_.MemberType) 
    Write-Host (" $" + "window.ADD_" + $_.name + "{   write-host """ + $_.name + """ }")
}

Write-Host "# ------------------------- Property ------------------------- "
$ret  = ($window | Get-Member -MemberType "Property") 
$ret |  Where-Object{ 
    Write-Host ("#TypeName:   " + $_.TypeName) 
    Write-Host ("#Definition: " + $_.Definition ) 
    Write-Host ("#Name:       " + $_.Name) 
    Write-Host ("#MemberType: " + $_.MemberType) 
    Write-Host (" $" + "window." + $_.name )
}
```

This code Can Make All Event Method and Property.

But All event methods and properties are not available in Power Shell

For exmample, window Active Method ( Add_Active ) is not use because of method is not found.

```
[System.Windows.Window] does not contain a method named 'ADD_Activate', so the method call
I failed to do so.
Occurrence location C:\PS\File name sample.ps1:669 Characters:2
+ $window.ADD_Activate{ write-host "Activate" }
+
```

So  I want to get an available list of events, methods, and properties For GUI using Xaml in PowerShell.

Comment: According to the output in your GitHub link, the event name is ```Activated```, not ```Activate``` per your error messsge, or ```Active``` as you’ve named it in the text of your post - is this a typo or the cause of your problem?

Comment: In this script, I commented out "ADD_Activate" because I knew it would cause an error. That line is ## $window.ADD_Activate{ write-host "Activate" }. If you would like to try it, could you please uncomment it and run it?

Comment: Also, for events and methods other than “ADD_Activate” that caused errors, I commented them out one by one using ##.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what your actual question is in that case - there is no event called ```Active```  or ```Activate``` on a ```System.Windows.Window``` object (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window?view=windowsdesktop-8.0), so I wouldn't expect ```Add_Activate``` to work. However, there *is* an ```Activated``` event, and ```$window.Add_Activated({write-host "aaa"})``` works fine here.. There is also a *method* called ```Activate``` but you'd invoke that like ```$window.Activate()``` - it's a method, not an event...

Comment: Thank you!   I tryed to other sample code  [gist](https://gist.github.com/papanda925/5c57e7af1d36d1e6b2c47bed8ff9523a#file-powershell_xaml_form_allevent_method_property_sample_verification-ps1)

Comment: I want to mechanically obtain Events and Methods that can be used in Xaml. To do this, I used the "Get-Member -MemberType "Event"" and Get-Member -MemberType "Method" commands.

Comment: But, umm... 
It seems that Get-Member commands also retrieves unnecessary information.

Comment: I would appreciate it if there was a way to determine whether xaml can be used by specifying the Get-Member option.